# Hw question on functions and generating outputs and inputs

Tags: r

[image]

I have figured out part A but I am having trouble with part b since most people would use cat but I am unfamiliar with it since my professor briefly went over it.

This is what I have so far

```
SS<-function(X){n<-length(Y)

sample_var<-sum((Y-mean(Y))*(Y-mean(Y)))/(n-1)

return(sample_var)}

#b

y<-rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1)#Normal[0,1]

print(y)

??
```

Comment: 1. Correct `SS<-function(X)` to `SS<-function(Y)` since you are using `Y` everywhere in the function body. 2. Have you tried `SS(y)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah    would it be                                                                                            y<-rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1)#Normal[0,1]
print(y)
Y<-c(y)
SS_y<-SS(y)
print(SS_y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SS<-function(X){n<-length(X)

sample_var<-sum((X-mean(X))*(X-mean(X)))/(n-1)

return(sample_var)}

#b

Y<-rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1)#Normal[0,1]

print(SS(Y))

#or
s=SS(Y)
print(s)

#c
E=exp(Y)
print(SS(E))
```

#c

output:

```
0.9667681

3.141597
```

Comment: I have a question in regards to SS<- function(Y), why is it not x? since the question says write a function SS(x) if you could just explain to me, thank you

Comment: It does the same thing, but I replaced with SS(X) now just to do exactly what the question asks. Thanks